# MATLAB Creating a .txt file containing numbers and strings from a cell

Tags: matlab

Dear stackoverflowers,

I'd like to create a .txt file using matlab.
The content should be separated with tabs.
It should have 3 columns, and the 3rd column should be filled with strings from a cell array.
Let's say

```
A=[2; 3; 3;];
B=2*A;
C=cell(3,1);
C{1,1}='string1'; C{2,1}='string2'; C{3,1}='string3';
```

In the end, it should look like this:

```
    2  4  string1
    3  6  string2
    3  6  string3
```

I already found out, how to put the 2 matrices in a text file:
dlmwrite('filename.txt', [A B], 'delimiter', '\t')

But how to append the content of the cell?
It would be best, to have only the strings in the file, not the single quotes.
I neither found a solution to this elsewhere, nor did I ask this somewhere else.
I apprechiate all kinds of suggestions.

Comment: Use cprintf to generate a character array and write it out to a file: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation on dlmwrite states:

> **Remarks**
>
> The resulting file is readable by spreadsheet programs.
>
> The dlmwrite function does not accept cell arrays for the input matrix
>   M. To export a cell array that contains only numeric data, use
>   cell2mat to convert the cell array to a numeric matrix before calling csvwrite.
>
> To export cell arrays with mixed alphabetic and numeric
>   data, where each cell contains a single element, you can create an
>   Excel spreadsheet (if your system has Excel installed) using xlswrite.
>   For all other cases, you must use low-level export functions to write
>   your data.

So either you write it as an Excel spreadsheet, or use have to write your own conversion function.

For example

```
A=[2; 3; 3;];
B=2*A;
C=cell(3,1);
C{1,1}='string1'; C{2,1}='string2'; C{3,1}='string3';

% First solution
f = fopen('filename.txt', 'w');
for n = 1:3
    fprintf(f, '%d\t%d\t%s\n', A(n), B(n), C{n});
end
fclose(f);

% Another solution
% create the table as a single cell array with only strings
C2 = [arrayfun(@num2str, [A, B], 'UniformOutput', false) C]'; % <- note the transpose

f = fopen('filename.txt', 'w');
fprintf(f, '%s\t%s\t%s\n', C2{:}); % <- every three entries are written as a line
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Thank you! At the moment I do not want to export it as a spreadsheet, but I might wanna do this in future.

Comment: @user1830121 ok, but the code I posted shows you two way of writing it as a TAB delimited textfile instead of a spreadsheet. I see that you´ve accepted Schifini's answer instead, but please note that the output of that answer is NOT TAB delimited, as you asked, but space delimited. Also, that answer uses the variable `i`, which may break other code in Matlab, since it is used the imaginary number.

Comment: Dear catchmeifyoutry, I originally marked the other solution, because I thought it looks more easy also for other users. Meanwhile I tried both suggestions with my real dataset and I found out that your 2nd solution works best!  If I use the 1st one, I somehow get this warning: The argument for the %s format specifier must be of type char (a string), which I do not get if I use the 2nd one (on the same cell, of course). However, I consider this questions as solved for me and am very thankful for your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
% Open a file for writing (if you want to append to file use 'a' instead of 'w')
fid = fopen(file,'w');

for i = 1:size(A,1)
    fprintf(fid,'%d  %d  %s\n',A(i),B(i),C{i})
end

fclose(fid)
```

Hope this helps